# Submit a Unity app to Windows store

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp

I have a unity app built for Windows desktop. Client wants this to be distributed through Windows 10 Store. This is just a desktop app and has no support to tabs or phones.
But looks like with Windows 10 there is no desktop only option.
Is there any documentation on what are the steps I need to follow to submit the unity built app to Windows store?

I did some reading and looks like this is what I will have to do.
https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/One-Dev-Minute/How-to-publish-your-Unity-game-as-a-UWP-app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/win_cert/windows-certification-portal

But want to get a confirmation from some one who has already done that. As I don't have a Windows developer account right now to try that out.

Comment: Honestly, I would say if they want that, then you might as well get the developer account so you can make sure it works, and know the steps your client will need to take.

Comment: I am interested about the answer of your question but to be fair stackoverflow is not the place to ask it. If no one answer it try in some other stack exchange stie :)

Comment: @Eddge thanks. But the thing is I want to know these info to do the estimate of that work (this is a small part of that) and need to do that soon and will not have much time to try out everything. So just wanted to get a rough idea how long this will take to do that part.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any documentation on what are the steps I need to follow to submit the unity built app to Windows store?

The steps of publishing a unity app is similar to UWP app. You can refer to [App Submissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-submissions) for more details.

After your packages have been successfully uploaded, you will find the Device family availability section that indicates which packages will be offered to specific Windows 10 device families.
For your requirement, you could  check **Windows 10 Desktop** device option, as the follow picture shows:
[image]

For more info, you could refer to [Device family availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/device-family-availability) official document.